# rightBarButtonItem add segue

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I want to add a segue and use the functionality of 'prepareForSegue' function. But can anyone please guide how to connect to a new controller from the rightbarbuttomitem of navigation view controller item? In the storyboard, i want to know how to connect the same, please guide and oblige.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just press ctrl+mouse and drag & drop it to the new view controller. It'll ask for 'Action Segue', use 'push', and name it(e.g 'Test Segue')

and in the view controller class, just define

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Test Segue"]) {
       // Do initializations
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Open your storyboard, press ctrl and mouse and move it to the second view controller. [image]

Select **push segue**. 
Your storyboard should look like: 
[image]

Select the segue and in Attributes inspector change the segue name.
And your code should be like this:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"segueName"]) {
     //To-do smth
  }
```